# How to enable Angular animations?

Tags: javascript, angular, debugging, animation

I've done everything by the tutorial (https://angular.io/guide/animations), but I have the error: `menu-navigation.component.html:1 ERROR Error: Found the synthetic property @slideTop. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.`

I read everything about it but did not find the answer on how to resolve it.

Files:

- app.ts: https://gist.github.com/yakimchuk/d2458a26e0a8b9a31f7d92d15885ee08
- parent-component-html: https://gist.github.com/yakimchuk/63ece812957a67a243cc2ab7cb03fd0a
- parent-component-ts: https://gist.github.com/yakimchuk/ea857a109a5c2cc644c16d800990d469
- animated-component.ts: https://gist.github.com/yakimchuk/71c7f3d756742e7e6d98d26f27e889d0
- transitions.ts: https://gist.github.com/yakimchuk/2ef55221aaeaf382d34aee7e77d31d3d

So I did:

- Imported animation modules in the root module (and added them into imports section)
- Described animation of the animated element
- Defined attribute about animation
- Did everything according to documentation

I tried:

- Replace BrowserAnimationsModule with NoopAnimationsModule: no result
- Replace "data: boolean" with "data: any" (in parent component): no result
- Check all NPM-modules versions: they are all 8.0.0 version, no result
- Check tutorial steps many times: no result
- Copy animation metadata from the tutorial and do everything like there, and still: no result

Guys, help me :)
I am stuck for already a few days.

**UPDATE:**
**Finally, I found the answer after testing on a new empty project**

If you defined "animations" to the component (prop), then you can use them only inside its component (its own html), but not within a parent layout.

Instead of "" you must move its amination inside that component (app-animated-comp).

Comment: Maybe I need to remove some NPM modules?

Comment: Can you reproduce demo in stackblitz ?

Comment: make sure you have imported `BrowserAnimationsModule` in the root module and not in any other module . Also  make sure that you have removed `BrowserModule` import from all other modules. Then stop the `ng serve` and rerun the command

Comment: @RomanYakimchuk also make sure that you have  mentioned   `slideTop` in the @Component.animations for the component class.

Comment: Yes, everything is done, not result

Comment: This is the problem, that's why I am writing here

Comment: @RomanYakimchuk i could see that you have imported both `BrowserModule` and `BrowserAnimationsModule` in the link please remove `BrowserModule`  : https://gist.github.com/yakimchuk/d2458a26e0a8b9a31f7d92d15885ee08

Comment: Just tried, no result

Comment: Is the component where you are using the animations, by change, in a separate module? If that is the case, you should import `BrowserAnimationsModule` to that module.

Answer (score 0):

BrowserAnimationsModule is an package you need to add in your app.module

https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

```
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule],
  ...
})
export class PizzaPartyAppModule { }
```

Comment: remove BrowserAnimationsModule from app.ts and any ts file. I saw you have it in the app.ts file and add it only in the module. Angular may be getting confused